# Web service looks up the closing price of a stock using python

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to Write a web service that looks up the closing price of a stock. Using Python Flask , or Goland

● In response to a GET request, the service should return the last NDAYS days of data
along with the average closing price over those days. For example, for aapl and
NDAYS=3, the GET response might look something like this:
○ appl data=[110.56, 111.25, 115.78], average=112.50

● The stock SYMBOL (the symbol to look up) and NDAYS (the number of days) are
environment variables provided to your program.
I also need to use apikey for sample query like this for example:

```
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events",
        "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-10-14",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2020-10-14": {
            "1. open": "223.0000",
            "2. high": "224.2200",
            "3. low": "219.1300",
            "4. close": "220.8600",
            "5. adjusted close": "220.8600",
            "6. volume": "23422344",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
            "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
        },
        "2020-10-13": {
            "1. open": "222.7200",
            "2. high": "225.2100",
            "3. low": "220.4300",
            "4. close": "222.8600",
            "5. adjusted close": "222.8600",
            "6. volume": "28950843",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
            "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
        },
        "2020-10-12": {
            "1. open": "218.7900",
            "2. high": "223.8600",
            "3. low": "216.8100",
            "4. close": "221.4000",
            "5. adjusted close": "221.4000",
            "6. volume": "40461368",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
            "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
        }
```

○ Rigorous error handling is not required. You can assume the stock exists, the
number of days is valid, etc.. In other words, this can be a quick and dirty
program - it does not need to be highly polished.

I have wrote this code so far , I am not sure how to grab the 3 days and average than how to set my code to be on a web server, it is not working , please help.

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
  
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
        return "Hello! This is the home page <h1>HELLO</h1>"

@app.route("/")
def user():

#Enter Key here
key = "mykey is here"
ts = TimeSeries(key)

aapl, meta = ts.get_daily(symbol= "AAPL")

print(aapl['2020-10-10'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

Comment: Okay, so what is the rule or logic that will tell you what the stock price is? And if you know that, then *what exactly do you need help with*?

Comment: The rule and logic to get the average of 3 days of a stock from the apikey listed , then print it to a web service. I need to how I can use GET request to a web service of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your bullet points it seems like you have some sort of guidelines which you are supposed to follow.

First, building this in a real world application, your API should be able to handle query params for example `http:/localhost:5000/api/[SYMBOL]?NDAYS=days`. Which will be like this in code:

```
# You can pass query params
# /api/AAPL?NDAYS=3
@app.route("/api/<symbol>")
def user(symbol):
    # You can now get the query parameters with
    # request.args.to_dict()
    # {"NDAYS": "3"}
```

However, since it is stated that NDAYS and SYMBOL are provided to you via environment variables you need to load them into your Python script first.

```
import os
@app.route('/average')
def get_average():
    stock = os.environ.get('SYMBOL')
    ndays = os.environ.get('NDAYS')
    # get the data from the JSON structure you are provided
    # and return it
```